# Reset ao autoincremento

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

tenho um problema na minha base dedos.
Eu tenho o código envio como auto incremento mas sempre que elimino um código envio o valor não da reset ou seja não recomeça vai sempre aumentando.
[image: Data table]

[image: Table definition]

Eu queria saber como dar reset ao numero...por exemplo em vez de começar no 36 começar no 1

Comment: Esse é o comportamento esperado do 'Auto incremento', uma vez inicializado irá ser sempre(auto) incrementado.

Comment: e nao ha maneira de dar reset?

Answer (score 2):

o que pode fazer é utilizar o seguinte comando:

## DBCC CHECKIDENT

Este comando verifica o valor de identidade atual da tabela especificada e, se necessário, altera o valor da identidade. Você também pode usar DBCC CHECKIDENT para definir manualmente um novo valor de identidade atual para a coluna de identidade.

```
BCC CHECKIDENT ( table_name [, { NORESEED | { RESEED [, new_reseed_value ] } } ] )
```

Os parâmetros são:

**table_name** - É o nome da tabela sobre a qual verificar o valor de identidade atual. A tabela especificada deve conter uma coluna de identidade. Nomes de tabelas devem ser compatíveis com as regras para identificadores.

**NORESEED** - Especifica que o valor de identidade atual não deve ser alterado.

**RESEED** - Especifica que o valor de identidade atual deve ser alterado.

**new_reseed_value** - O novo valor a ser usado como o valor atual da coluna de identidade.

> Para o seu caso em específico creio que o comando:
>
> ```
> DBCC CHECKIDENT ('dbo.envios', RESEED, 1)
> ```
>
> Resolva o problema.

Mais informações [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms176057.aspx).

Comment: e onde coloco isto???

Comment: Olha, eu teria que ver seu código. Depende muito da sua necessidade.